# Locus runs for first time for subsequent run i get The value of "start" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 2 ** 53 - 1. Received -25586

Tags: node.js

I have a block of code in node. It runs perfect but when i add locus eval(require('locus'))
i get an error The value of "start" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 2 ** 53 - 1. Received -25586. When i uninstall and reinstall locus it works for first run and in subsequent request it fails. Could some one help here

```
async postUpdate(req, res, next){
        // find the post by id
        let post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        console.log(req.body);
        // check if there's any images for deletion
        //eval(require('locus'));
        if(req.body.deleteImages && req.body.deleteImages.length) {
```

Answer (score -1):

What version of locus are you using? I was on 2.0.4 and faced the same problem. Installing 2.0.3 helped me and now it works just fine - hope it'll help you too. Good luck!